# How to convert tuple to seconds?

Tags: python, sql, datetime

I am running an sql query in python.

TIMEDIFF()

It gives me the result just fine.

<class 'tuple'>
(datetime.timedelta(days=-1, seconds=86332),)

I want to convert this to be only seconds.

I tried to add the seconds as interval into my query but it cannot be run that way.

Select Timediff(second, ...)

I also tried DATEDIFF, not worked.

After I add the 'second' the query cannot be executed

So, I want to calculate in pyton the difference, if no other solution.

Comment: Please update the description using backticks and clearer question will be better.

Comment: get the first item of the tuple, and then use timedelta methods to get the seconds

Comment: `(datetime.now() - datetime.now()).total_seconds()`  of course, in reality using different times

Answer (score 0):

You can get the `timedelta` object from the tuple using indexing:

```
td = result[0]
```

then get the number of seconds using the `timedelta` object's `total_seconds` method.

```
seconds = td.total_seconds()
```

Comment: <pre>
```
t = (datetime.timedelta(days=-1, seconds=86332),)

print(type(t))

td = t[0]

print(td)
print(type(td))
seconds = td.total_seconds()

print(seconds)
print(type(seconds))
```
<code>
<class 'tuple'>
-1 day, 23:58:52
<class 'datetime.timedelta'>
-68.0
<class 'float'>